# Sigma-algebra genrated by two random variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I've found in this site the question:
"let $(X,U)$ $(Y,V)$ independent random vectors, s.t. X and Y are real valued r.v.s with finite expectations. Show that then:

$$E[XY|(U,V)]=E[X|U]E[Y|V]."$$

Now to prove it i should prove that given $H=E[X|U]$ and $J=E[Y|V]$:
$HJ$ is $\sigma(U,V)$-measurable and that
 $\forall A \in \sigma(U,V), \, E[XY \cdot 1_A]=E[HJ \cdot 1_A].$

The problem is that i don't get what $\sigma(U,V)$ is. 
This is what i've thought:

$X:(\Omega,\Sigma_x,P_x)\rightarrow (\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R)), \;Y:(\Omega,\Sigma_y,P_y)\rightarrow (\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R)),$

$U:(\Omega,\Sigma_u,P_u)\rightarrow (\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R)),$ $V:(\Omega,\Sigma_v,P_v)\rightarrow (\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R)).$

Where $\Sigma_x=\sigma(X)$ and the same for $\Sigma_y,\Sigma_u$ and $\Sigma_v$.

Now if i want to condition with respect to both $U$ and $V$ then i should have $$\{U^{-1}(q)\cap V^{-1}(p): q,p \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R) \} \subseteq \sigma(U,V)$$  but $U^{-1}(q) \in \sigma(U)$ and $V^{-1}(p) \in \sigma(V)$ (and those are the elements of the two $\sigma$-algebras by definition ) so that means that $\{A \cap B: A \in \sigma(U),B \in \sigma(V)\} \subseteq \sigma(U,V).$

For the property of $\sigma$-algebras we have that $$\forall A \in \sigma(U) \rightarrow (A \cap \Omega)=A \in \sigma(U,V)$$ and the same holds for every $B \in \sigma(V).$

So we have that $(\sigma(U) \cup \sigma(V)) \subset \sigma(U,V)$, but if i take $\Sigma=\sigma(\sigma(U) \cup \sigma(V))$ (the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the union of the two $\sigma$-algebras) then $\forall A \in \sigma(U) \rightarrow A \in \Sigma$ and the same is also true for $B \in \sigma(V)$.

Finally we also have that: $$(A \cap B) \in \Sigma, \; \forall A \in \sigma(U), \forall B \in \sigma(V).$$ Then since $\Sigma$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\sigma(U)$ and $\sigma(V)$ we have $\Sigma \subseteq \sigma(U,V)$.

Now i'm wondering shouldn't be $\sigma(U,V)=\Sigma?$ Because if i think about the event $(U=u,V=v)$ that is just $(U^{-1}(u)\cap V^{-1}(v))=(A \cap B) \in \Sigma $, but i don't know if it is enough to just take the counterimages of $u,v \in \mathbb R$ instead of all the counterimages of $u,v \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your post is very difficult to read. Consider breaking it into paragraphs or something..

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i hope it is fine now.

Comment: What are $U$ and $V$? It doesn't seem to be explicitly stated in your post.

Comment: The statement is just copied from another question as i wrote, but since $(X,U)$ and $(Y,V)$ are random vectors then $U$ should be a r.v. defined on a common probability space with $X$, and the same should hold for $Y,V$.

Comment: Yes, $$\sigma(\sigma(U)\cup\sigma(V))=\sigma((U,V))$$